# Angular UI Modal CSS

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the Angular UI modal and would like to make it smaller.  According to Bootstrap's website, to make the modal smaller I should use the modal-sm modifier class:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

I'm having trouble incorporating this div into my Angular modal template.  Every Angular UI modal example I have found includes only the modal-header, modal-body, and modal-footer divs in the template.  Are the outer modal, modal-dialog, and modal-content divs already provided by Angular?  If so, is there any way to overwrite them so that I can apply "modal-sm" to the modal-dialog div?  I tried adding the full modal div structure to the template and it caused problems with my modal.  I also tried setting windowClass = "modal-dialog modal-sm" in my controller but that didn't work either.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

**Update:** here is the content of my modal template after I tried to include the outer Bootstrap div's.  It is a very simple modal to confirm the user wants to delete an item.

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Confirm Delete</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               <p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="confirm()">Confirm</button>
               <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The result is it doesn't show my modal correctly.  I can see the backdrop and a very tiny sliver of what I assume to be my modal.

**Update:** Using @lmyers's solution worked for me, but instead of specifying the width as 60% I did the following to make use of the @modal-sm Less variable.

```
.confirm-modal .modal-dialog {
    width: @modal-sm;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the content you are putting in your modal? Have you tried controlling the size of the modal by controlling the size of the content?

Comment: I updated the question with the contents of my modal template.  As you can see there is very little content inside my modal so the size of the content is not an issue.  I just want to use modal-sm to make my modal smaller than the default size.

Comment: I have a nearly identical modal dialog for confirm delete, without the outer divs, and it sized itself appropriately. So I'm wondering what version of bootstrap? What's in your .css? You may have to look in Chrome at the styles that are being applied to this dialog to debug.

Comment: What size is your modal?  I'm wanting one sized like what displays when you click the Small Modal button on (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).  What I'm getting out of the box is the same size as the static example which seems to be the default size.  I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and Angular UI 0.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I understand now. Here's what we did in the .css:

```
.appcustom-modal-med > .modal-dialog {
  width: 60%;
}
```

then in the controller:
    windowClass: 'appcustom-modal-med'

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution is fairly simple and worked for me, but instead of specifying the width myself I used the @modal-sm Less variable.  That makes me feel a little better that I can't simply use the modal-sm modifier in my template.  I saw modal-sm and modal-lg are new as of Bootstrap 3.1.0 so maybe at some point Angular UI will allow us to use those modifiers to customize the size of the modal.

Comment: I updated my question with how I used the @modal-sm Less variable.

Comment: Interestingly, I searched through the Angular UI issues and found an issue for this - (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1718).  Reading through the comments, there is a pull request in progress to be able to apply classes to modal-dialog.